# Even simple commands take a long time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I installed the developer edition of `SQL Server` on my laptop running Windows 10 Pro. The laptop has six `cores`, each core burstable to 3.5 GHz. The computer has 8GB of `RAM`, and a `SSD`.

When I run even simple commands under `SSMS` on the same machine as `SQL Server` like:

```
SP_HELPINDEX 'TableName'
```

it takes 15 seconds to come back with an answer. `C#` commands to query the table often time out to the point where I have to increase the timeout from the default to 35 seconds. I look at the CPU usage on the machine, and it is not taxed - mostly 35% usage over the `cores`. Something is wrong, I just don't know what it is. Any tips on making `SQL Server` more responsive?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long to return a response, SQL can run on a relatively poorly specced machine - the question is memory though, have you checked to see how much process memory SQL is requiring and are you filling the cache with data (do you have GBs of data in your tables? Do you see this performance issue twice in a row - i.e. if you run the same query batch twice it takes the same time or the second run is much faster?).

Comment: The only thing could be the ridiculously low RAM (for these days) - if SQL Server is struggling in an environment it can not get RAM, swapping could lead to that slow answers. Otherwise - no idea. This is definitely NOT normal behavior. I would ask on dba.stackexchange.com, but be prepared to do some basic analysis of how busy the machine is, not just "25% usage" - which, btw., is EXTREMELY high for not doing anything, so - is there an anti virus scan running in the background and you have a hard disc, not ssd?

Comment: @TomTom remember when Doom used to run on half a meg of ram...

Comment: RAM is low for what you normally see on a development machine where you want to run MSSQL and some IDE like VS which is also a resource hog. I would start there, use the task manager to see if the RAM use is peaking and the bytes in use by SQL Server and possibly other processes. You can also sort your processes by RAM use descending.

Comment: [Don't trust Task Manager](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/01/19/stop-using-task-manager-to-check-sqls-memory-usage/) - it will always lie about process memory. Use the DMVs and performance counters to get a more accurate picture. Also, to reduce the load on an 8GB machine, which is less memory than a lot of phones and tablets, consider using [containers](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Learn-How-to-Deploy-SQL-Server-2019-in-Containers-in-Just-Minutes), [localdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/), or cloud.

Comment: I  closed my browsers, removed NVidia Control Panel and Docker from the startups, and it is considerably faster. I didn't isolate what the problem is, but I have a suspicion that it was NVidia or Docker.